# Android application: "The Application has stopped unexpectedly" - using setText() method

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with my Android application. If I use setText() method for a textView I have problem like: The Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Code of the application:

```
public class TC1 extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tc1);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Hi"); // wrong line
}
...
}
```

XML fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tc.TC1$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: LogCat my friend LogCat??

Comment: are you sure @+id/textView in activity_tc1.xml ?

Comment: Yes. I solved this problem, thank's for help to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView is part of the Fragment xml but you try to get it from the Activity layout. Move the `findViewById()` call to the `onCreateView()` method of your Fragment.

For future questions:
Please do not quote `"The Application has stopped unexpectedly"` instead check the `LogCat` output for error messages and stack traces. The error message you quoted is the default crashed information for the user, nothing that provides any detailed informations for us developers.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, R.id.container,false);
```

**and change**

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

**to this**

textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

Your code is currently trying to access your main activities view which does not contain your textview.   Another option is to access it through your fragment in a similar fashion.

Comment: I could not create inflater instantion, but I solved this problem a other code. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `textview` is part of `fragment` not `activity_tc1`.

So either use `textview` in `activity_tc1` layout. or use `textview` in `onCreateView` method of fragment. where `fragment_tc1` will be your fragment name.

For example

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tc1, container,
                    false);

           TextView  textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           textView.setText("Hi"); 
            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works :)

Comment: @user3770088 Happy to help,if this answer helped you then please accept it,so it may help others also, having similar issue,anyway enjoy coding.